# Vue iterar 2 array en un v-for con campos que tienen una relacion

Tags: laravel, array, vue.js

**Quiero mostrar dos array en una tabla**

---

veran tengo dos arrays en el primero tengo los productos y el segundo tengo los estados de los productos y tiene un campo producto_id al que hace referencia.

```
                   <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>name</th>
                                <th>estado</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="pro in productos" :key="pro.id">
                                <td>{{pro.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{pro.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{aqui quiero mostrar el estado del segundo arry}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Estos son los arrys:

```
 productos:[
              {id:1, name: 'gaseosa'},
              {id:2, name: 'carne'},
              {id:3, name: 'pasta'},
              {id:4, name: 'arroz'},
              {id:5, name: 'queso'},
          ],
          estadoProducto:[
              {id:1, status: 'activo', producto_id:1},
              {id:2, status: 'inactivo', producto_id:4},
              {id:3, status: 'activo', producto_id:3},
              {id:4, status: 'activo', producto_id:5},
              {id:5, status: 'inactivo', producto_id:2},
          ],
```

agradeceria mucho su valiosa ayuda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mi opinión es agregar una `computed property` para no sobrecargar el template. Lo recomendable es no poner demasiada lógica en los templates.

**JS**

```
  computed: {
    productosConEstado: function () {
      // utilizando se map agrega la propiedad estado por cada elemento del array productos
      let productosConEstado = this.productos.map(p => {
        p.estado = this.estadoProducto.find( (el) => { return el.producto_id === p.id } ).status
        return p
      })
      return productosConEstado
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>estado</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="pro in productosConEstado" :key="pro.id">
        <td>{{pro.id}}</td>
        <td>{{pro.name}}</td>
        <td>{{pro.estado}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Es más fácil si juntás los dos arreglos en uno solo. De esa manera, podes recorrer el arreglo obtenido con un v-for. Si esos arreglos los obtenés con una petición Ajax, en el momento que recibis la respuesta del servidor, los transformas en algo como esto:

```
productos:[
   {id:1, name: 'gaseosa', status: 'activo'},
   {id:2, name: 'carne', status: 'inactivo'},
   {id:3, name: 'pasta', status: 'activo'},
   {id:4, name: 'arroz', status: 'inactivo'},
   {id:5, name: 'queso', status: 'activo'}
]
```

Otra solución, que creo que es más correcta y que responde mejor a tu pregunta es usar el método "find" para arreglos.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<tr v-for="pro in productos" :key="pro.id">
   <td>{{ pro.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ pro.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ estadoProducto.find(el => el.producto_id == pro.id).status }}</td>
</tr>
```

Pero si tenes que soportar al infame IE, el método mencionado no está soportado por ese navegador. Sin embargo, hay un polyfill en esta página que podes aplicar: [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) y además, en ese caso, deberías reemplazar las funciones flecha por funciones comunes. Quedaria así sin funciones flecha:

```
<tr v-for="pro in productos" :key="pro.id">
   <td>{{ pro.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ pro.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ estadoProducto.find(function(el) { return el.producto_id == pro.id; } ).status }}</td>
</tr>
```

Saludos!

Comment: interesante respuesta pero que pasa si nos los puede unir? si forzosamente debe trabajarlos como vienen en su pregunta?

Comment: @shadow, puede ser. No lo descarto. Agregé otra respuesta.

Comment: no @Pedro urday como ya te comenté mas abajo eso no es válido en esta comunidad, dale editar a esta respuesta y añade todo lo que haga falta

Comment: deja solo una y borra la otra

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega a esta respuesta, la otra que habias puesto ;)

Comment: agrega tambien como seria sin funciones flecha. no sabemos si OP sabe transformarlas ;)

Comment: Recién la edité. Disculpen, no volverá a suceder.

Comment: No hay ningun problema Pedro.. si no leiste el [tour], te sugiero leerlo. Y tambien podes leer [answer]

Answer (score 5):

Voy a dejar otra respuesta, pero la de Pedro es valida.

Simplemente vamos a hacer lo mismo, pero usando directamente VUE. de esa forma no tenemos que agregar ninguna libreria externa y no dependemos de problemas de navegadores ya que se va a transpilar solo a algo compatible.

Y ademas, hace exactamente lo mismo, ya que el metodo find, recorre el array y solo muestra el elemento que cumple dicha condicion. Pero que pasaria si dos o mas cumplen?

```
 <tr v-for="pro in productos" :key="pro.id">
     <td>{{pro.id}}</td>
     <td>{{pro.name}}</td>

     <td v-for="e in estadoProducto" :key="e.id">
         <span v-if="e.producto_id == pro.id">
             {{e.status}}
         </span>
     </td>
     </tr>
```